# Python: Tkinter - I am creating a bunch of "+1" texts but their not deleting and they are lagging my game up, help please

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, helper

so basically the "+1", "+2" texts I'm creating for my game that is like cookie clicker aren't deleting and its lagging up the game hard. I need some help, heres the code.

```
def update1Positions():
    global onesYpositions, onesPictures

    for i in range (0, len(onesYpositions)):
        onesYpositions[i] = onesYpositions[i] - 2
        if onesYpositions[i] <= 60:
            screen.delete(onesPictures[i])
        deleteOnes()

def drawOnes():
    global onesPictures, currentBlob
    for i in range(0, len(onesYpositions)):
        if currentBlob == 1:
            onesPictures[i] = screen.create_text( 591, onesYpositions[i], text = "+1", font = "Times 15", fill = "black"  )
        if currentBlob == 2:
            onesPictures[i] = screen.create_text( 591, onesYpositions[i], text = "+2", font = "Times 15", fill = "black"  )
        if currentBlob == 3:
            onesPictures[i] = screen.create_text( 591, onesYpositions[i], text = "+4", font = "Times 15", fill = "black"  )
        if currentBlob == 4:
            onesPictures[i] = screen.create_text( 591, onesYpositions[i], text = "+8", font = "Times 15", fill = "black"  )
        if currentBlob == 5:
            onesPictures[i] = screen.create_text( 591, onesYpositions[i], text = "+20", font = "Times 15", fill = "black"  )
        screen.update()

def deleteOnes():
      for i in range(0, len(onesYpositions)):
          screen.delete(onesPictures[i])

def deleteOnes2():
    global onesPictures
    if len(onesPictures) > 10:
        screen.delete( onesPictures )
```

Thats the code for the +1 and 2 texts, I put the deleting in a while loop in the runGame function. Can't post all code, its 800+ lines. If you know a way that will delete them after a certain point, that would be great.

The last function there is my own attempt but it didnt work!

Answer (score 0):

You can associate a tag with your items, then delete allitems that have that tag with a single delete command.